# Unable to run 'Hello World' application error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Tags: android, android-layout

I am newbie in Android app development.

I am using Android Studio and created sample/new project of 'myapplication' as stated on this site:  
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html

I have successfully run this program on my Android device running on version 4.2. 
However, I remover package Android4.4W SDK from SDK manager. And deleted this project and recreated. Now, whenever I am trying to run this program. I am getting following error:

```
Installing com.example.ashv.myapplication DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.ashv.myapplication"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.ashv.myapplication
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

Notes:

- I have delete existing installed filed from device.
- I have check that following set 'android:minSdkVersion="17"'.
- I have set it to 15 but it doesn't help.

> Is 'Android4.4W SDK' is mandatory to run application on device?

(I can not install this package, after this studio doesn't render Android view (activity.xml design tab) with 'TextView' and shows error (render exception). That's why I have removed this package).

Please suggest.

Comment: No, Android4.4W SDK is not mandatory. It is the SDK for developing devices for android wearables.

Comment: Thanks Shivam for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution and would like to share.

Whenever i was creating my project, a file gradle.build (containing all tags like android:minSdkVersion="17", android:targetSdkVersion="17" etc.) were not updating values according to my device version even i was selecting correct version of API while creating project in android studio.

I have renamed my project and it worked.
Anyway, thanks for looking into my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I create a new project In the Minimun SDK option I selected Google APIs(Google Inc)(API18) instead of API18:Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean).